# android 10 heads-up notification listening

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on an app. in which I am listening to incoming call notifications. but there is a problem on some devices like android 10 and 11 . for an incoming call, there is no notification in android 10 and 11. I have searched a lot and I found that this is called [heads-up notification.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up)  how can I listen to the head-up notification from the default device dialer?

Comment: facing the same issue. please check for telephone manager in android. i am. working in react nativr ao dont have a deep knowledge of this.

Comment: have you found a solution for this. the only solution that is found if you want to get a mobile number. you have to listen to call states. and to get the mobile number you have to add the CALL_LOG permission. an incoming call heads-up notification does not have a mobile number.